# How to send mouse click event to a game application?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, window

I try to send a mouse click event to a game application. First, i use Spy++ to find what message the application receive. I see something like : WM_MOUSEACTIVATE, WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING, WM_ACTIVATEAPP, WM_ACTIVATE, WM_SETFOCUS, ...
i try to send the same as i see on Spy++ but it doesn't work. How to send mouse click to a game application without give it focus? . it's run in window mode. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note that if you intend to create a cheat for a game, that is probably the less reliable/elegant way to do it :)

Comment: Post some code as how you are sending the messages. And how you get the handle to the games window.

Comment: :) .. Ya .. i try to write an bot-program(auto ?). i dont know how to call it in english. This game dont have any protecter like X-trap, N-Protect game guard, .. . Can you tell me how i can do it ? what should i learn ? . I spent a lot of time sending message to it XD

Comment: Here some code i do : Get handle : HWND hRO = FindWindow(L"GameClassName", L"GameWindowName"); (take from Spy++).SendMessage(hRO, WM_MOUSEACTIVATE, 0x00190476, 0x02010001);
 SendMessage(hRO, WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING, 0, 0x0018FA50);
 SendMessage(hRO, WM_ACTIVATEAPP, 1, 0);
 SendMessage(hRO, WM_ACTIVATE, WA_CLICKACTIVE, 0);
 SendMessage(hRO,WM_NCACTIVATE, 1, 0);
 SendMessage(hRO, WM_SETFOCUS, 0, 0);
 PostMessage(hRO, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, MK_LBUTTON, MAKELONG(200,200));
 PostMessage(hRO, WM_LBUTTONUP, MK_LBUTTON, MAKELONG(200,200));
 SendMessage(hRO, WM_KILLFOCUS, 0, 0);

Answer (score 1):

You want WM_LMOUSEDOWN. You can always check MSDN for the documentation on which messages mean what.

Comment: is it same as `WM_LBUTTONDOWN`?

Comment: I send WM_LBUTTONDOWN also, i check MSDN for every message i send. I also check Spy++ and i see my application receive all message that i sen, but it still doesnt work. i dont understand.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to automate applications and games is via [SendInput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646310%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). While in theory it should be possible to drive an application via WM_LUBTTONDOWN etc, many applications read the key state directly via lower level APIs (such as GetAsyncKeyState) which don't change their state to reflect the messages processed from the message queue.

Using SendInput requires actually setting the game to the foreground as the input events are synthesized at a low level and are thus delivered to the active/focused window.

Comment: I tried : INPUT minput;
 minput.type = INPUT_MOUSE;
 minput.mi.dx = 200;
 minput.mi.dy = 200;
 minput.mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN;
 minput.mi.time = 0;SetForegroundWindow(hRO);
 Sleep(5000);
 if(SendInput(1, &minput, sizeof(INPUT)) == 0)
  MessageBox(0,L"SENDINPUT ERROR", L"ERROR", 0);. i run and click to game window manually, it has a LBUTTONDOWN but at my mouse position, not at 200:200.

Comment: If i dont click on game window, it click at my mouse position. i mean it have a LBUTTONDOWN state so it work as i click left mouse and drag around.